# how to direct to another activity after successful login, Android Developer Studio

Tags: java, android

as i said, how do i direct to the next activity after successfully login? im kinda stuck for a while now, and it is necessary for this to run. im practicing my android skills awhile back.  so i am using android developer studio for my practices of developing android. this is my code. hope you guys can help.

```
`package com.mikesaclolo.pinasarap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;

 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
 Button b1,b2;
 EditText ed1,ed2;

 TextView tx1;
 int counter = 3;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tx1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&

                    ed2.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                tx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                counter--;
                tx1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                if (counter == 0) {
                    b1.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}`
```

Comment: What problem you are getting ?

Comment: use an explicit intent to start another activity refer http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleExplicit here they have considered service..you can use activity

Comment: its not directing to the next activity.. sorry i did not include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start activity using `Intent` :

```
if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("admin") && 
          ed2.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class); // redirecting to LoginActivity.
       startActivity(intent);
  }
```